# How do I set the image path in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, image, hyperlink

I am using absolute paths for images on a WordPress site (currently in dev) but when the page loads the images are missing.

Here is an example:

```
<img src="/images/img_tonsmeire-properties.png" alt="tonismere" >
```

The only thing I can think that may be causing this is that the dev environment that I am creating this in is not at the root of the parent site. The URL for this is is:

```
http://opteracreative.com/~baybr/
```

What is the correct way to reference the images?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the path. I had to add /~baybr/ in front of the image path and it worked.